# How to compare each row against each other and get the best result?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Suppose I have a table of values and categories:

```
+--+-----+---+
|ID|value|cat|
+--+-----+---+
|0 |1    |0  |
+--+-----+---+
|1 |3    |0  |
+--+-----+---+
|2 |2    |1  |
+--+-----+---+
|3 |1.2  |1  |
+--+-----+---+
|4 |1    |1  |
+--+-----+---+
```

And I want to know, for each row, the ID of the row which matches the value most closely *and* belongs to the same category, and I also want to know the difference.

So for row `ID=0` the correct answer would be `ID=1`, and the difference value would be `2`. The correct output would be this:

```
+--+----------+----------+
|ID|difference|best match|
+--+----------+----------+
|0 |2         |1         |
+--+----------+----------+
|1 |2         |0         |
+--+----------+----------+
|2 |0.8       |3         |
+--+----------+----------+
|3 |0.2       |4         |
+--+----------+----------+
|4 |0.2       |3         |
+--+----------+----------+
```

I'm just learning about `CROSS JOIN` and while I'm sure this can be done I don't really know where to start.

Comment: I don't see how this question could be clearer. If you don't like it please provide a suggestion as to how I can clarify what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a self-join and making use of the `ROW_NUMBER()` function in conjunction with `MIN()`:

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT a.ID aID
                    ,MIN(ABS(a.value - b.value)) diff
                    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.ID ORDER BY MIN(ABS(a.value - b.value)))RN
                    ,b.ID bID
              FROM Table1 a
              JOIN Table1 b
                ON a.cat = b.cat
                AND a.ID <> b.ID
              GROUP BY a.ID,b.ID)
SELECT  aID
       ,diff
       ,bID Best_Match
FROM cte
WHERE RN = 1
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cd94df/5/0)

If you want to return multiple rows in case of a tie, you'd want to use `RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`